# How can I import three.js's JSON into Maya?

Tags: json, three.js, maya

I would like to import JSON(made by three.js) data into Maya. 
I found exporter of Maya, but couldn't find importer of Maya.
Is there good way to do it?

Comment: but why you  do this maya is 3d modeling and rendering tool and JSON is representation of the format into javascript understanding code and three js is utility for rendering it on webgl why you need to reverse it..?? does it make sense on doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are currently no Three.js JSON importer.

The Three.js JSON is meant to be a runtime format, used by Three.js for rendering in WebGL. Usually, you would export *to* the JSON format when you want to use it for the web. It is not meant to be a storage format.

There are other more common "interchange" formats like FBX, Collada, or OBJ, that are meant to be for storage and for passing around between different people and software packages.

Comment: I assume you're asking the question because you don't have access to the original file. In this case, the JSON file is actually not that difficult to read, and if you're savvy enough with your text editor or in some light scripting, you should be able to convert it to OBJ without much trouble.